# reorder columns according to values in a row in bash or awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have

```
200 34  323 160  
0.3 0.6 0.5 0.2  
0.4 0.9 0.7 0.9
```

and need

```
34  160 200 323  
0.6 0.2 0.3 0.5  
0.9 0.9 0.4 0.7
```

.. columns sorted by value in the first row. In bash or awk. Sounds simple but..

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: It is possible, but somewhat annoying and rather suboptimal, to do it with `sort` and `awk` (transpose, sort, transpose). It would be much easier if you could use a higher language like Ruby, or at least Perl (which is pretty much guaranteed to be installed anywhere). http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48020/60565

Comment: I spent quite some time to understand (I think so) that bash sort will not do this - only sorts rows. In awk I can do it if I knew the order (just awk '{print $2 $4 $1 $3}' ) but my files are big and many. I thought of transposing the matrix sorting with sort and transposing back, but this sounded stupid.

Comment: This question may be of some interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577235/sort-entries-of-lines-using-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {print $i " " i} }' inputfilename >headers.txt
sort -k1,1n headers.txt >headerssort.txt
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$2} NR!=FNR {for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {printf $a[i] " "}; print $a[NF]}' headerssort.txt inputfilename >outputfilename
```

Essentially what you do is creating temporary file `headers.txt` that has all the values from the 1st line of your input file (`inputfilename`) printed on the separate line, plus the position of this value (column number) in the input file. Then you sort this file according to the value (still keeping the original column number of course) and obtain `headerssort.txt` file. And finally you use this sorted file to print columns in the correct order resulting in the desired file (`outputfilename`).

Comment: Thanks very much. This seems logical. But when I run it I get the values all in one column.  34  
160  
200   
323
0.6 
0.2 
0.3 
0.5
0.9 
0.9 
0.4 
0.7

Comment: @maitbb: Make sure that in the last command you have `printf` instead of `print` (followed by regular `print`). That should fix this problem. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Why are you splitting instead of just using the fields in awk ?

Answer (score 2):

A way all in awk
Will work with any amount of fields.

```
awk 'NR==1{split($0,a,FS);asort(a);for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)b[$i]=i}
          {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf("%s ",$(b[a[i]]));print x}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

what about simple one:

```
awk '{print $2,$4,$1,$3}' file
```

Comment: Well, this will only work with the example, and not with any other file.

Comment: No, it's not - see his comment.